# Php recursive method

Tags: php, recursion, tail-recursion

I am trying to retrieve all my products of the current and child categories recursively, but unfortunatly it always returns an empty array. Here is my method.

```
class Category {

    public static $products = [];

    public static function products($id) {

        array_merge(self::$products, DB::table('products')->where('category_id', $id)->get());
        $categories = DB::table('categories')->where('parent_id', $id)->get();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            self::products($category->id);
        }
        return self::$products;
    }   

}
```

After executing this method Category::products is an empty array. Can someone help me find the correct way to do this?

Comment: you never add any products to the Categoriy::products array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `array_merge`. It returns a new array, it doesn't modify the argument array.

```
self::$products = array_merge(self::$products, DB::table('products')->where('category_id', $id)->get());
```